# Creating a simple obj reader in c++ that reads vertices, vertice normals, and faces for both

Tags: c++, vector, extract, vertices, reader

I have already made an object reader that can store vertice data and faces of a shape in two separate vectors:

```
void main(){
fstream modelfile("Cube.obj", ios_base::in);

if (modelfile.is_open())
{
    vector <float> verticesCoordsXYZ;
    vector <float> faceCoords;
    string line;
    while (getline(modelfile, line))
    {

        string s;
        istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> s;


        if (s == "v")
        {

            float x, y ,z;
            iss >> x >> y >> z;
            verticesCoordsXYZ.push_back(x);
            verticesCoordsXYZ.push_back(y);
            verticesCoordsXYZ.push_back(z);


        }

        if (s == "f")
        {
            int a, b, c;

            iss >> a >> b >> c;

            int aLocation = a * 3 - 3; //vertice locations in verticeCoordsXYZ that would make up faces
            int bLocation = b * 3 - 3;
            int cLocation = c * 3 - 3;

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                faceCoords.push_back(verticesCoordsXYZ.at(aLocation+i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                faceCoords.push_back(verticesCoordsXYZ.at(bLocation+i));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                faceCoords.push_back(verticesCoordsXYZ.at(cLocation+i));
            }

            cout << endl << a << b << c <<endl;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)verticesCoordsXYZ.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << verticesCoordsXYZ.at(i);

    }

    cout << endl << verticesCoordsXYZ.size() << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)faceCoords.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << faceCoords.at(i);
    }
    cout << endl << faceCoords.size() << endl;
    modelfile.close();

    system("pause");

}
```

**Explanation:**

I need to expand the program so that it can also put all vertex normals into a vector in order they appear, and all vertex normals into a vector in order they appear in f lines of the obj file

The problem is that in my current version of the program the f lines were written just for vertex coords and appeared as following:

f  1  7  5

but in expanded version, using a new object file, f lines are written for both vertex coords and vertex normals and appear as following:

f  1//2  7//2  5//2

This means that in my current, simpler version of the program I can just use this code to extract face values: iss >> a >> b >> c;

but I cannot do that anymore because of the slashes in between the values.

**Question:**

What can I do to extract values before slashes as ints for vertex coordinates, and extract values after the slashes as ints for vertex normals, avoiding slashes inbetween them?

Comment: I suggest this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKFYtekgnP8&index=10&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP
This is java, but with a minimal extra effort you'll be able to write it in c++

Comment: or this, c++ code included
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS980twY1ZE&index=12&list=PLEETnX-uPtBXT9T-hD0Bj31DSnwio-ywh